# jQuery each().height() in native JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to have the same height for all bootstrap card-headers, card-bodys and card-footers. I couldn't find a way to do this without JS.
I found a jQuery Code (https://codepen.io/felinuxltda/pen/KKVVYYN?editors=1111)

```
var x = 0;
$(".card-deck .card-header, .card-deck .card-footer")
  .each(function (id, it) {
    if ($(it).height() > x) {
      x = $(it).height();
    }
  })
  .height(x);
});
```

I converted this code to native JS but I have to loop multiple times.

```
var header = 0;
var body = 0;
var footer = 0;
document.querySelectorAll(".card-header, .card-body, .card-footer").forEach(function (element){
    if (element.classList.contains('card-header')){
        if (element.offsetHeight > header) {
            header = element.offsetHeight;
        }
    } else if (element.classList.contains('card-body')){
        if (element.offsetHeight > body) {
            body = element.offsetHeight;
        }
    } else if (element.classList.contains('card-footer')){
        if (element.offsetHeight > footer) {
            footer = element.offsetHeight;
        }
    } 
});
document.querySelectorAll(".card-header").forEach(function (element){
    element.style.height = header;
});
document.querySelectorAll(".card-body").forEach(function (element){
    element.style.height = body;
});
document.querySelectorAll(".card-footer").forEach(function (element){
    element.style.height = footer;
});
```

I wonder if there is a similar way to do jQuery "each().height()" in native JS.

Comment: Would it not make sense in the initial DOM query to maintain a list of each type of element you care about? Then if the height is greater than the previous highest, iterate over the newly maintained list of that type, setting the height style property?

Comment: First of all - that jQuery code doesn't even do the same thing, as your own version. The jQuery version doesn't do anything to the height of the `.card-body` elements, but more importantly - it sets the _same_ maximum height for all `.card-header` _and_ `.card-footer` elements. (Like, duplicate the content of the last `.card-footer` element in that codepen, and you will see the card headers grow to that same height.)

Comment: And `$(...).height(x)` simply has the looping already "build in." Feel free to create a construct _similar_ to what jQuery is doing, if you think that makes you code more readable - a function that gets a selector and a callback function passed, and then it "executes" that selector via `document.querySelectorAll`, forEaches over the result, and applies the callback function to each element.

Comment: `let header = Math.max(...[...document.querySelectorAll(".card-header")].map(d => d.offsetHeight));`

Comment: @PhilGolding I'm completely open minded. But after hearing CBroe I guess I just stick to my part as it works like intended. I didn't nkew height has the Loop implemented. Could have looked this up tbf.

Comment: Yep - in my answer, I suggest the same thing. jQuery has been around plenty of time to have done the relevant performance enhancements, and resolving all the edge cases. It's the right call if you're not explicitly trying to avoid bringing a dependency on jQuery in.

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor this further, creating a single function that could accept parameters based on each element type, but I believe this is what you're attempting to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var header = 0;
  var body = 0;
  var footer = 0;

  const headerElements = [];
  const bodyElements = [];
  const footerElements = [];

  const updateElementHeights = (elements, height) => {
    elements.forEach((element) => {
      element.style.minHeight = height +"px";
    });
  };

  document
    .querySelectorAll(".card-header, .card-body, .card-footer")
    .forEach(function (element) {
      if (element.classList.contains("card-header")) {
        headerElements.push(element);
        if (element.offsetHeight > header) {
          header = element.offsetHeight;
          updateElementHeights(headerElements, header);
        } else if (element.offsetHeight !== header) {
          element.style.minHeight = header +"px";
        }
      } else if (element.classList.contains("card-body")) {
        bodyElements.push(element);
        if (element.offsetHeight > body) {
          body = element.offsetHeight;
          updateElementHeights(bodyElements, body);
        } else if (element.offsetHeight !== body) {
          element.style.minHeight = header +"px";
        }
      } else if (element.classList.contains("card-footer")) {
        footerElements.push(element);
        if (element.offsetHeight > footer) {
          footer = element.offsetHeight;
          updateElementHeights(footerElements, footer);
        } else if (element.offsetHeight !== footer) {
          element.style.minHeight = footer +"px";
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Though I suspect your best option is rolling with the jQuery alternative if it's a viable option. It's probably already been massively optimised, whereas this has been cobbled together to meet your requirements!

Comment: This uses nested loops which cause the height of all elements being adjusted every time a bigger element is found instead of only once when the maximum height is found making it worse then the original code. I also think that the readability is worse.

Comment: "Worse" than the original code is subjective. As mentioned, it could do with a refactor to look better - I agree.
I was simply removing the requirement to loop through all elements again at the very end, as asked for. 
I also provided the final statement, saying that jQuery is definitely the better choice.